# firebase emulators:exec not running vitest tests correctly

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools, vitest

I'm setting up my first test suite with firestore in a relatively fresh vue3/vite/vitest project.

I have a test file, `firestoreRules.test.js` that works fine when I start the firestore emulator with `firebase emulators:start --only firestore` and then run my tests with a `npm run test` in another tab. This isn't so great in a CI environment, and is obviously what the `firebase emulators:exec` however I haven't had any success running my test workflows with it.

my relevant package.json:

```json
...
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
"test-once": "vitest run"
"test-rules": "firebase emulators:exec --only firestore \"npm run test-once\""
...
```

Here are some of the things I've tried:

###### `firebase emulators:exec --only firestore "echo hi"`

This worked great at greeting me

###### `firebase emulators:exec --only firestore "npm i"`

This worked great at installing node modules

###### `firebase emulators:exec --only firestore "npm run test-once"`

This failed after the emulator started with a `/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option --`. I couldn't figure out what that was about since I didn't see an `--` anywhere, but eventually I found a github answer about pointing me to putting the command in a script

###### `npm run test-rules` aka `firebase emulators:exec --only firestore "npm run test-once"`

this seems to choke on some ESM issue:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986
    throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, true)
    ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/.../node_modules/vitest/vitest.mjs not supported.
```

This doesn't make any sense to me as there isn't a `require` in the entire `vitest` package. Or why would it fail in emulators:exec context when running `vitest` directly works just fine.

I don't exactly know where to dig in more most everything else I have tried gives something like the above. It seems like either vitest might be incompatible with however it is being ran in the firebase emulator, or hopefully there is some adjustments I can make to get the script runner to work with out having to set up some kind of time base execution of the emulator in CI.

I haven't found anything close to what I'm doing with the firebase emulator and vue/vitest so I'm hoping that this question may help others who are not having luck searching.

Thanks!